# FactoryBoy / Django - OneToOneField duplicate key error

Tags: django, factory-boy

I am writing tests for a large Django application with multiple apps. As part of this process I am gradually creating factories for all models of the different apps within the Django project.

However, I've run into some confusing behavior with FactoryBoy

Our app uses `Profiles` which are linked to the default `auth.models.User` model with a `OneToOneField`

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    birth_date = models.DateField(
        verbose_name=_("Date of Birth"), null=True, blank=True)
    ( ... )
```

I created the following factories for both models:

```
@factory.django.mute_signals(post_save)
class ProfileFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):

    class Meta:
        model = profile_models.Profile

    user = factory.SubFactory('yuza.factories.UserFactory')
    birth_date = factory.Faker('date_of_birth')
    street = factory.Faker('street_name')
    house_number = factory.Faker('building_number')
    city = factory.Faker('city')
    country = factory.Faker('country')
    avatar_file = factory.django.ImageField(color='blue')
    tenant = factory.SubFactory(TenantFactory)


@factory.django.mute_signals(post_save)
class UserFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):

    class Meta:
        model = auth_models.User

    username = factory.Faker('user_name')
    first_name = factory.Faker('first_name')
    last_name = factory.Faker('last_name')

    email = factory.Faker('email')
    is_staff = False
    is_superuser = False
    is_active = True
    last_login = factory.LazyFunction(timezone.now)

    profile = factory.RelatedFactory(ProfileFactory, 'user')
```

Which I then run the followings tests for:

```
class TestUser(TestCase):

    def test_init(self):
        """ Verify that the factory is able to initialize """
        user = UserFactory()
        self.assertTrue(user)
        self.assertTrue(user.profile)
        self.assertTrue(user.profile.tenant)


class TestProfile(TestCase):

    def test_init(self):
        """ Verify that the factory is able to initialize """
        profile = ProfileFactory()
        self.assertTrue(profile)
```

All tests in `TestUser` pass, but the `TestProfile` fails on the factory initialization ( `profile = ProfileFactory()`) and raises the following error:

```
IntegrityError: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "yuza_profile_user_id_key"
DETAIL:  Key (user_id)=(1) already exists.
```

Its not clear to me why a duplicate User would already exist, (there should only be one call to create one right?, especially since any interfering signals have been disabled)

My code was based on [the example](https://factoryboy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/recipes.html#example-django-s-profile) from the FactoryBoy documentation, which also dealt with Users / Profiles that are connected via a `OneToOneKey`

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

**Update**

As per the suggestions of both Bruno and ivissani I've changed the `user` line in the `ProfileFactory` to

```
user = factory.SubFactory('yuza.factories.UserFactory', profile=None)
```

Now all the tests described above pass successfully!

However I still run into the following issue - when other factories call the `UserFactory` the

```
IntegrityError: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "yuza_profile_user_id_key"
DETAIL:  Key (user_id)=(1) already exists.
```

still returns.

I've included an example of a factory calling the `UserFactory` below, buts its happening to every factory that has a `user` field.

```
class InvoiceFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):

    class Meta:
        model = Invoice

    user = factory.SubFactory(UserFactory)
    invoice_id = None
    title = factory.Faker('catch_phrase')
    price_paid = factory.LazyFunction(lambda: Decimal(0))
    tax_rate = factory.LazyFunction(lambda: Decimal(1.21))
    invoice_datetime = factory.LazyFunction(timezone.now)
```

Changing the `user` field on the `InvoiceFactory` to

```
user = factory.SubFactory(UserFactory, profile=None)
```

Helps it pass some of the tests, but eventually runs into trouble since it no longer has a profile associated with it.

Weirdly the following (declaring the user before the factory) DOES work:

```
self.user = UserFactory()
invoice_factory = InvoiceFactory(user=self.user)
```

Its not clear to me why I still keep running into the `IntegrityError` here, calling the `UserFactory()` now works fine.

Comment: As per the documentation example, you are missing to pass `profile=None` to the `SubFactory` field definition. Not quite sure why you get `IntegrityError` but your `ProfileFactory` should look like `user = factory.SubFactory('yuza.factories.UserFactory', profile=None)`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think it's because your `ProfileFactory` creates a `User` instance, using the `UserFactory` which itself tries to create a new `Profile` instance using the `ProfileFactory`.

You need to break this cycle, as described [in the documentation you link to](https://factoryboy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/recipes.html#example-django-s-profile):

```py
# We pass in profile=None to prevent UserFactory from 
# creating another profile (this disables the RelatedFactory)
user = factory.SubFactory('yuza.factories.UserFactory', profile=None)
```

If this doesn't work for you and you need more advanced handling, then I suggest implementing a [`post_generation` hook](https://factoryboy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference.html#factory.post_generation) where you can do more advanced things.

*EDIT:*

Another option is to tell Factory Boy to not recreate a `Profile` if there is already one for the `User` by using the [`django_get_or_create` option](https://factoryboy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/orms.html#factory.django.DjangoOptions.django_get_or_create):

```py
@factory.django.mute_signals(post_save)
class ProfileFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):

    class Meta:
        model = profile_models.Profile
        django_get_or_create = ('user',)
```

If you do so, you might be able to remove the `profile=None` that I suggested before.

*EDIT 2:*

This might also help, change the `UserFactory.profile` using a `post_generation` hook:

```py
@factory.django.mute_signals(post_save)
class UserFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):

    class Meta:
        model = auth_models.User

    ...

    # Change profile to a post_generation hook
    @factory.post_generation
    def profile(self, create, extracted):
         if not create:
             return
         if extracted is None:
             ProfileFactory(user=self)
```

*EDIT 3*

I've just realised that the `username` field in your `UserFactory` is different from the one in factroy boy's documentation, and it's `unique` in Django. I wonder if this doesn't cause some old instances to be reused because the username is the same.

You may want to try changing this field to a sequence in your factory:

```py
@factory.django.mute_signals(post_save)
class UserFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):

    class Meta:
        model = auth_models.User

    # Change to sequence to avoid duplicates
    username = factory.Sequence(lambda n: "user_%d" % n)
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! I changed the code and the tests above now pass successfully! However, the problem reappears when other factories call the UserFactory.

I've updated my original post - would you be so kind to take a look?

Comment: That did it! Thanks!